# Describing lego brick dimensions in Japanese

Tags: readings, symbols

In English in order to describe a Lego brick which has dimensions or 2 pegs by 4 pegs, we could say "2 x 4" and pronounce this "2 by 4". How is this expressed in Japanese?

I have seen "2 x 4" written on a Japanese lego site, but would this be pronounced "二　カケル　ヨン"?

I assume this is similar to how one would describe a matrix in Japanese (like in English), but if anyone knows any specific lego terms let me know.

Also, to describe a brick with those dimensions would "2 x 4" be sufficient, or is it better to say "2 x 4 (の)ブリック"?

Answer (score 3):

I'd say

> ニ カケル ヨン の レゴブロック

though I never had a chance to describe the dimension of a LEGO brick in Japanese.  I didn't order them some 27 yrs ago, my parents did :-)

Most Japanese don't understand what is a "brick."  LEGO bricks are known as レゴブロック [LEGO *block*], or simply レゴ, in Japan.

Answer (score 2):

I believe dimensions are read as:

> A対{たい}B

Same as in mathematics when you have a ratio such as:

> A:B

Also, bricks are commonly called blocks in Japanese.

> レゴブロック

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about that way of saying it. I found this site which says "2x4ブリック", which usage do you think is more common?
http://technicfreaks.shop-pro.jp/?mode=cate&cbid=1608958&csid=12

Comment: @Locksleyu interesting. I haven't heard that one before, but it seems prevalent on the web.

Comment: This is interesing, because in a ratio, this is a division (:). In the case of a Lego brick, or say, a grid, this is a multiplication (×). I’d like to hear from a native Japanese, how they’d read stuff like “4×2のブロック” or “3×3のマス”.